# How to run a Pytorch code on several GPUs?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, multi-gpu

I have multiple GPU devices and want to run a Pytorch on them. I have already tried [MULTI-GPU EXAMPLES](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html) and [DATA PARALLELISM](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html) in my code by

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0,1,2")
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[0, 1, 2])
model.to(device)
```

in my code. But the training is still performed on one GPU (cuda:0). In the shell, I have also selected GPUs using `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2` before running my code.

Could anyone help me to solve this issue please?

Comment: setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` makes only one GPU device "visible" for your process, it cannot see the others and hence cannot utilize them. try unsetting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`

Comment: how many devices does pytorch sees? Have you tried running `torch.cuda.device_count()`?

Comment: With this (as an example) `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1`, I specify 3 GPUs like `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2`. Pytorch sees all of them, but runs on only one.

Comment: How did you determine your code is only running on one GPU?

Comment: By `watch nvidia-smi`. The other two GPUs were idle. On one GPU, I get out of memory error, too.